# Treeview with Parent and Child objects

Tags: c#, .net

Good day,

Can someone please assist me with populating a treeview with child objects.

My file layout looks like this.

```
Fruits
apple,green,red
banana,yellow,green
Vegtables
Pumpkin,yellow
Beans,Green

Output should be :
+Fuits
   -apple,green,red
   -banana,yellow,green
+Vegtables
   -Pumpkin,yellow
   -Beans,Green
```

I am using regular expression to match my strings, If I found a Header I want to make a parent, if a found a sub item under the header I want to make a child.

The matching part work 100% but my tree view is not working.

```
int counter = 0;
if (filename.Trim() != string.Empty)
{
   System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
   string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split(' ');
   while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       Match match = regex.Match(line); //Match Header
       Match matchSub = regexSub.Match(line);//Match Detail
       TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();

       if (match.Success)
       {
           newNode.Text = line;
           treeCards.Nodes.Add(newNode);

       }
       else if (matchSub.Success)
       {

           TreeNode newNode1 = new TreeNode();
           newNode.Nodes.Add(newNode1);
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "is not working". Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces whatever specific problem it is you are actually asking about. It looks to me like your main problem is that you are allocating `newNode` for every line of text, rather than just when the header changes. But with such a vague question, I can't really say for sure, since I don't even know what specific problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new tree node representing a header for each iteration of a while loop. While, it should be created only if a header was found (i.e. when `match.Success == true`). Try something like this:

```
var currentHeader = null;
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Match match = regex.Match(line); //Match Header
    Match matchSub = regexSub.Match(line);//Match Detail

    if (match.Success)
    {
        currentHeader = new TreeNode();
        currentHeader .Text = line;
        treeCards.Nodes.Add(currentHeader);
    }
    else if (matchSub.Success)
    {
        var newNode = new TreeNode();
        newNode.Text = line;
        currentHeader.Nodes.Add(newNode1);
    }
    counter++;
}
```

I assumed that your regular expressions work correctly. Besides, please note that this code does not perform any validation. If an input file has a wrong format it may cause an exception. I recommend to add a validation step to your program.